# Finding shortest sublist with sum greater than 50

Tags: python, list

I have a list and I want to find shortest sublist with sum greater than 50.
For example my list is

```
[8.4 , 10.3 , 12.9 , 8.2 , 13.7 , 11.2 , 11.3 ,10.4 , 4.2 , 3.3 , 4.0 , 2.1]
```

and I want to find shortest sublist so that its sum is more than 50.

Output Should be like  `[12.9 , 13.7 , 11.2 , 11.3, 10.4]`

Comment: by smallest what do you mean, smallest by size or smallest by values

Comment: by smallest subarray you mean a `sub = arr[i:i+n]` such that `n` is minimum? can you post an expected output?

Comment: Can there be negative numbers in your array?

Comment: smallest by size

Comment: @KanikaSinghal Do you want sublist or subsequence of your list?

Answer (score 2):

## *O(n)* solution for list of positive numbers

Provided your list *cannot contain negative numbers*, then there is a linear solution using two-pointers traversal.

Track the sum between both pointers. Increment the right pointer whenever the sum is below 50 and increment the left one otherwise.

This provides a sequence of pointers within which you will find the ones with minimal distance. It suffices to use `min` to get the smallest interval out of those.

Due to the behaviour of `min`, this will return the left-most sublist with minimal length if more than one solution exists.

### Code

```
def intervals_generator(lst, bound):
    i, j = 0, 0
    sum_ = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if sum_ <= bound:
                sum_ += lst[j]
                j += 1
            else:
                yield i, j
                sum_ -= lst[i]
                i += 1
        except IndexError:
            break

def smallest_sub_list(lst, bound):
    i, j = min(intervals_generator(lst, bound), key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
    return lst[i:j]
```

### Examples

```
lst = [8.4 , 10.3 , 12.9 , 8.2 , 13.7 , 11.2 , 11.3 ,10.4 , 4.2 , 3.3 , 4.0 , 2.1]
print(smallest_sub_list(lst, 50)) # [8.4, 10.3, 12.9, 8.2, 13.7]

lst = [0, 10, 45, 55]
print(smallest_sub_list(lst, 50)) # [55]
```

## Solution for general list of numbers

If the list can contain negative numbers then the above *will not work* and I believe there exists no solution more efficient than to iterate over all possible sublists.

Answer (score 2):

this is way bad solution (in term of not doing all graph serach and find optimum values ), but solution is correct

```
lis =[8.4 , 10.3 , 12.9 , 8.2 , 13.7 , 11.2 , 11.3 ,10.4 , 4.2 , 3.3 , 4.0 , 2.1] 


from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(len(lis)):
    dic[lis[i]]+=[i]

tmp_lis = lis.copy()
tmp_lis.sort(reverse=True)

res =[]
for  i in tmp_lis:
    if sum(res)>50 :
        break
    else:
        res.append(i)

res1 = [(i,dic[i]) for i in res]

res1.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
solution =[i[0] for i in res1]
```

output

```
[12.9, 13.7, 11.2, 11.3, 10.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort it in descending order and sum the first elements until you hit +50.0.

```
myList = [8.4 , 10.3 , 12.9 , 8.2 , 13.7 , 11.2 , 11.3 ,10.4 , 4.2 , 3.3 , 4.0 , 2.1]

mySublist = []
for i in sorted(myList, reverse=True):
    mySublist.append(i)
    if sum(mySublist) > 50.0:
        break

print mySublist  # [13.7, 12.9, 11.3, 11.2, 10.4]
```

Considering that what you want is the smallest sublist in size, and not the smallest in sum value.

Comment: If OP uses the term sub-array correctly, then any reordered or non-consecutive numbers is wrong.

Comment: If your list is constant in size, I read somewhere that complexity is O(1). If it is not, I think complexity is O(n), but I'm not sure as I forgot all of that. It'd be great if someone could clarify.

Comment: O(nlogn) is complexity here

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for **any** shortest sublist, this can be a solution (maybe to be optimized):

```
lst = [8.4 , 10.3 , 12.9 , 8.2 , 13.7 , 11.2 , 11.3 , 10.4 , 4.2 , 3.3 , 4.0 , 2.1]

def find_sub(lst, limit=50):
    for l in range(1, len(lst)+1):
        for i in range(len(lst)-l+1):
            sub = lst[i:i+l]
            if sum(sub) > limit:
                return sub

>>> print(find_sub(lst))
```

Output:

```
[8.4, 10.3, 12.9, 8.2, 13.7]
```